# Don't have access to Heroku app

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

I have a mystery app in Heroku. It's called weird-app-5536

When I try to push my code to Heroku I get this message:

```
  Your account my_email@geemail.com does not have access to weird-app-5536.
 !  
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: *************************************************

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I try...

```
heroku apps
```

I get a list of my apps, but it does not include the mystery app, weird-app-5536.

I can't destroy or rename the weird-app-5536 app. It always says I don't have access.
The app does not appear on my list of apps on the Heroku website.

When I type

```
git remote -v
```

I get this:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:weird-app-5536.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:weird-app-5536.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:thisisme/my_code.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:thisisme/my_code.git (push)
```

I deleted my old ssh keys. I created a new one and added it to Heroku

I can create new apps and they show up on my list of apps.

As far as I know I only have one Heroku account.

Stumped. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Its likely it was an app shared with you and your access was removed or you have cloned the app from heroku and then deleted it. Git and heroku are 2 seperate systems, so your git remotes may just be out of date.

Comment: Are you still struggling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happened is the git repo on which you're working is tied to an old remote. No need to contact heroku or anything... Just remove the heroku git remote and readd it.

Remove by running:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Readd with:

```
heroku git:remote -a appname
```

More here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would try to get a hold of Heroku support.  It might be possible that you were listed as a contributor to another app by someone but weren't given write access? Heroku support is probably your best bet.